# Heroku create - not uploading ssh key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-xp, heroku

I am in the process of deploying my Rails app to Heroku.  I am developing on Windows XP.  I've created my public SSH key, it loaded in my github account and it test out okay over ssh.  The issue is that when I create heroku application it never uploads my key.  I'm prompted for my email and password and then it just give me an application URL (which check out okay.)  When I then try to push my app to Heroku is gives me an error - **Permission denied (publickey).  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

The only thing that I can guess is that the 'heroku create' command can not find my ssh key.  Is there anyway to specify the path to the key.  I have a .heroku folder with a credential file in my home directory.  I'm stumped.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have you run the heroku command to upload your ssh key to their servers?

```
heroku keys:add
```

You should see something like "Uploading ssh public key C:\Users[name].ssh\id_rsa.pub"

Answer (score 2):

Managing your SSH Keys: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: This wasn't quite my fix but it was a good read.  Thanks (and upvoted.)